# Define a colour depending on a variable

Tags: color, conditionals, etoolbox

I'm trying to set a colour depending on the content of a variable. Please have a look at the MWE below. In case of `\junk{A}` the text should be red on a green background. In case the content of `\junk` is not A, then the background should be blue. However the background is always blue. What am I doing wrong?

beamersthememwe.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememwe}
\def\junk#1{\def\@junk{#1}}
\junk{A}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\ifstrequal{\@junk}{A}{
   \definecolor{background}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
}{
   \definecolor{background}{RGB}{0, 0, 128}
}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg = foreground, bg = background}
```

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usetheme{mwe}
  \junk{A}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Lipsum}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `\@junk` with `A` and of course “false” is returned. This is because `\ifstrequal` performs no expansion.

So you need to expand `\@junk` before the comparison takes place.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememwe}
\def\junk#1{\def\@junk{#1}}
\junk{A}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{foreground}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\@junk}{A}{%
   \definecolor{background}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}%
}{%
   \definecolor{background}{RGB}{0, 0, 128}%
}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg = foreground, bg = background}
```

[image]